# Why the definition of a measurable function in extended real numbers is more convenient?

Tags: real-analysis

In some books, the notion of measurable functions is defined on a measurable set into the extended real number set. Why is it convenient in the extended real case?

What does it mean that an $L^p$ function is defined a.e.? Does it mean that an $L^p$ function may take infinity on a zero-measure subset?

Comment: Yes, this is convenient for dealing with functions that have singularities.  For example, you might consider $f(x) = 1/\sqrt{|x|}$ on $\mathbb R$, giving it the value $\infty$ at $x=0$.  Or if you prefer, just leave it undefined at $x=0$.  In general, we don't care about what happens on sets of measure $0$, because two functions that agree except on a set of measure $0$ have the same integrals.